# How to automatically add chapters to videos in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to automatically populate videos with chapters or does every video have to manually have chapters entered? I have a large list of videos I would like to upload, all with their own lists of chapters. I'm looking for an easier solution than manually entering every timestamp.

I've created a Python script that automatically creates chapters for videos and uses ffmpeg to upload the chapter metadata in the video. I would like to upload videos to Sharepoint that include these chapters, but I've noticed that Sharepoint has their own manual version of creating chapters for videos that are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SharePoint has their own manual version of creating chapters for videos that are uploaded, the specific steps are:

1. Upload videos first
2. Open videos, find the Video settings in the upper right corner, change the status of Chapters to On, and you can start adding Chapters manually. For details, please refer to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7vGeswggHc).

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes/acceptance votes here. This has been removed from your posts already.

Comment: I know SharePoint has their own manual version of this. I was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically, rather than manually creating chapters for every video. I would like to be able to automatically fill chapters through the description or metadata if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is currently no built-in feature in SharePoint to automatically add chapters to videos. Including the officially recommended [MS stream](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-manual-chapters-with-videos-on-stream-on-sharepoint-8bbf61eb-c00b-42b5-a514-cce2e45eb6ea) also requires manual operation.
To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to [feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others.